# How to set minimum word count in wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am planning to create a code filter and set a minimum word count in saving/submitting the wordpress post. I tried this code.

```
function minWord($content)
{
    global $post;
    $content = $post->post_content;
    if (str_word_count($content) < 300 ) //set this to the minimum number of words
    wp_die( __('Error: your post is below the minimum word count. It needs to be longer than 300 words.') );
}
add_action('publish_post', 'minWord');
```

but the issue, when I input `< 300` words the `post` still saves it on the database. My question now is what should I do that if the content will have `< 300` words it won't save to the database?

Comment: You can not prevent publish of post with the help of this hook. By the time this hook is triggered, post is already published. However, you can change/revert post status in this method.

Comment: Look into this filter called: **wp_insert_post_data** https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **wp_insert_post_data** hook will be called before the post is saved to the database. We also check the status of the post so this function doesn't run on other admin pages.

```
function enforceMinWordCount( $data, $post )
{           
    if ($data['post_status'] === 'publish' &&
        str_word_count($post['post_content']) < 300 ) {
        wp_die( __('Error: your post is below the minimum word count. It needs to be longer than 300 words.') );

    }
    return $data;
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'enforceMinWordCount', 99, 2 );
```

This isn't very UX-friendly however, since a user will lose their post and get sent to an error screen. I'd recommended setting the status of the post to *pending* if it doesn't meet the minimum word count requirements, and notifying the user via the **admin_notices** hook that it cannot be published until the word count is reached.

Answer (score 0):

use 'save_post' hook . Try below code.

```
 function minWord( $post_id ) {

         $content = get_the_content( $post_id )
        if (str_word_count($content) < 300 ) //set this to the minimum number of words
        wp_die( __('Error: your post is below the minimum word count. It needs to be longer than 300 words.') );
        return;
     }
    add_action( 'save_post', 'minWord' );
```